# create generic class to update properties of several classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have an asp.net core application which uses this class "Form" with the following properites:

```
public abstract class Form
{
    public string SentByName { get; set; }
    public string SentByEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedByDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have several classes which inherit from this class (e.g.):

```
public class Customer: Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }   
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}


public class Account: Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountIdentifier { get; set; }   
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that data from a view model is passed to a create action on a controller and from the view model properties a Customer instance is created alongside some logic in the controller to apply values to the properties inherited from the Form class.

eg.

```
Customer thisForm = new Customer();

thisForm.FirstName = vm.FirstName;
thisForm.Surname= vm.Surname;
thisForm.SentByEmail = "ds@ds.com";
thisForm.SentByName = "DS";
thisForm.ReceivedByDateTime = DateTime.Now

_IMGP1DFC.Add(thisForm);
```

So you can imagine, I am duplicating these last three lines over and over for each controller action where a create is occuring for a given model.

What I would like to do is create some kind of generic service where any object that inherits from Form could be passed in and have those three attributes updated with particular values.

Can anyone tell me how I could create a class that would accept either a Customer or an Account so that I could update those similar attributes with one class... e.g.

```
public class AttributeMapper {

   private SomeKindOfFormObject _aForm;   

   public AttributeMapper(SomeKindOfFormObject aForm) {
      _aForm = aForm;
   }

   public SomeKindOfFormObject mapIt () {
      _aForm.SentByEmail = ....
      ..... 
      return aForm;
   }
}
```

(Eventually those hardcoded values for names and email would be replaced with authenticated user's info, so I would in turn have to bring those into the service as a separate issue)

Thanks!

Comment: so the property values for Form class are constant ? or dynamic ?

Comment: if you are looking for an automated approach then you can create a type of Form in your view model and then use automapper for the mapping purpose.

Comment: the three i have listed in this example will be constant. e.g. a customer is created, SentByName, and SentByEmail and ReceivedByDateTime will never change

Comment: if those are constant then why cant you directly assign the values ? you can directly assign the property values in the class itself.

Comment: Sounds like something that an interface would solve. Define the interface with those 3 properties, implement within your form, then work with the interface in your map method. Otherwise, you could just change your SomeKindOfFormObject to Form (your abstract class)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass your values in constructor

```
public abstract class Form
{
    public Form(string xx, string yy)
    {
        SentByName = xx;
        SentByEmail = yy;
        ReceivedByDateTime = Date.Now;
    }
}


public class Customer: Form
{
    public Customer(string xx, string yy) : base(xx,yy)
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }   
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
Customer thisForm = new Customer("DS","ds@ds.com" );
//if these values is special for Customer, setting them in constructor

thisForm.FirstName = vm.FirstName;
thisForm.Surname= vm.Surname;

_IMGP1DFC.Add(thisForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor in Form that fills the properties

```
public abstract class Form
{
    public string SentByName { get; set; }
    public string SentByEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedByDateTime { get; set; }
    public Form()
    {
        this.SentByEmail = "ds@ds.com";
        this.SentByName = "DS";
        this.ReceivedByDateTime = DateTime.Now
    }
}
```

then make the inherited constructors like this:

```
public class Customer: Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }   
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Customer() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Or if you are using latest version of C# just try this:

```
public abstract class Form
{
    public string SentByName { get; set; } = "ds@ds.com";
    public string SentByEmail { get; set; } = "DS";
    public DateTime ReceivedByDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: passing values like this for the latest version of c# could work for me. the final implementation would have values SentByName and SentByEmail coming from a class that extends IdentityUser. I'm not sure how I could bring these in in this case.